# Is "did you thought" a valid expression?

Tags: verbs, tenses

I saw a picture earlier that had a line that said "Did you thought, that was me?" and wondered, "Isn't it supposed to be 'Did you think [...]'?".

However, after using Google, I found this phrase being used quite frequently, and it has about 136 million hits on the exact search term of "did you thought".
If you replace 'thought' with other verbs in the exact same tense, it also doesn't really make sense.

I'm severely confused. My mind tells me this can't be right, yet it seems to be frequently (mis)used? Can anyone clarify on this?

Comment: The number Google returns for hits on expressions in quotes is ***completely meaningless***. That is, they may bear no relation whatsoever to reality. [Here](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=Did+you+thought%2C+did+you+thought%2C+Did+you+think%2C+did+you+think&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cdid%20you%20thought%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2CDid%20you%20think%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cdid%20you%20think%3B%2Cc0) are some more meaningful statistics.

Comment: I taut I taw a puddy tat

Comment: @mplungjan I did, I did.

Comment: This question rests upon a typographical, grammatical, or logical error or similar misunderstanding either in the question or in the text being asked about. While similar questions may be on-topic here, this one is unlikely to help future readers. This can often be avoided by consulting a good dictionary or searching within written works before posting.

Comment: The only way I can see it being correct is where A recalls seeing a photo of C and thinks it was of B. A, later, talking to B, relates what happened and B responds, 'Did you? Thought that was me?' 'You' is implied before 'Thought'. Otherwise, as you've written it, it's a no-no.

Comment: "I paid the bill, at least I thought I did". "They're coming to repossess my car. You thought you **did. You thought** you did. Get out!"

Answer (score 9, accepted):

"Did you thought" is incorrect in all standard varieties of English. The fact that you can find it on the internet doesn't prove anything. The internet is full of non-native speakers of English, who make these kinds of errors (and other errors) quite frequently.